# Selenium WebDriver (node js/ C#)-Element not visible/No such element exception while trying to send value to a search box

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Using Selenium WebDriver, trying to test the search feature on website https://www.healthdirect.gov.au/. I get "no such element/element not visible" exception everytime, same code works for other searches like google.

Javascript(Node js) snippet:

```
driver.get('https://www.healthdirect.gov.au/');

var search = driver.findElement(By.css('#header-search'));//tried with id,name,xpath elements and got same exception

search.sendKeys('fever');
```

C# snippet(with added wait):

```
 string searchEngine = "https://www.healthdirect.gov.au/";

 IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

 driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(searchEngine);

 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(25));

 wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Id("header-search")));

 driver.FindElement(By.Id("header-search")).SendKeys("fever");
```

Code from the website to find elements:

```
        <ul class="dropdown-menu hda-head_menu-row-tablet-search-list" role="listbox" position="position">
                            </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever such error occurs, make sure there not multiple matches of your object. I just checked Firebug and you can see there are 3 matching nodes and the one your are interested in is the second one

[image: Multiple matches]

Expected solution is to loop through the elements

```
var elems = driver.FindElement(By.Css("#header-search"))
```

Loop through them and check `IsDisplayed` and click the one which is displayed. Because they will change based on Mobile or Desktop resolution